# Rerender a Map component again

Tags: react-native, rerender, flatlist

```
 function getData(desp) {
        const v1 = desp.filter(item => item.new === false).length
        const v2 = desp.filter(item => item.apt === true).length
        const v3 = desp.filter(item => item.apt === false).length

        return [{ v:v1 },
        { v:v2},
        {v:v3 }]
    }
```

Render in the view

```
{getData

(data).map(item => {
                                    return (
                                        <View key={item}>
                                            <Text>{item.v}</Text>
                                        </View>
                                    );
                                }
                                )}
```

I am using this but as the data changes this component is not rerender. Only desp new and apt is changing.I want to rerender it. Also tried with Flatlist that is also not worked. Please check it and provide a solution

Comment: add data to the state of the component and change it using hook when your data get changed.

Comment: Re render is caused only when the state or props changes. So set the data to some state variable in getData function.